# PHP echo associative multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional associative array and display all of its values.

How do I do that using for loop?

Similar code:

```
$StudScore = array( 
    "Mary" => array(
        "physics" => 35,        
        "maths" => 30,      
        "chemistry" => 39       
    ),
    "Tom" => array(
        "physics" => 30,
        "maths" => 32,
        "chemistry" => 29
    ),
    "Jon" => array(
        "physics" => 31,
        "maths" => 22,
        "chemistry" => 39
    )
);
```

Comment: using foreach to loop the array

Comment: if you just want to display the contents of an array (or any variable), use [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this recursive function and see if it fits:

```
function echoArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<li>$key</li>";
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo "<ul>";
            echoArray($value);
            echo "</ul>";
        } else {
            echo "<ul><li>$value</li></ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

Change the way you display each item as you wish.

Comment: You never echo the values, just the keys.

Comment: Typo... fixed! Thanks.